# colgroup background color not override tr background color

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a col in colgroup with background-color grey.

I have a tr with background color orange

```
<table >
    <colgroup>
        <col class="col"  />
        <col  />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
.col{
    background-color: grey !important;       
}

.tr{
      background-color: orange; 
}

table{

    width: 100%;
}
```

I want col color override tr color.

how can i do?

in the example, 3 must be grey but is orange

http://jsfiddle.net/VsgA6/1/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kaciyasa/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS specification states that the column background is applied only if both the cell and row have transparent backgrounds (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns).

You have to set your color on the `tr` or the `td`.

For example with `td:first-child {background: grey}`

Comment: Another solution I decided to use was to set the background-colour of the alternate stripes to for example rbga(200,200,200, 0.1). This way, you can see the highlight through the zebra stripes. Very fast and clean solution with few downsides.

Answer (score 0):

If you need first `TD` in each row grey, use:

```
td:first-child {background: grey}
```

Comment: thanks, but the first col is grey for example, a value in the database cause a column to be grey

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<table >
    <colgroup>
        <col class="col" />
        <col class="col"  />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="tr">4</td>        
    </tr>
</table>




 .col{
        background-color: grey !important;       
    }

    .tr {
          background-color: orange; 
    }

    table{

        width: 100%;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewDta)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of n-th child TD specs like

```
TD:first-child {background: grey}
TD:nth-child(2) {background: red}
```

for overriding TR background-color you can also mix the colors by using a partially transparent TR or TD color instead of orange like

```
.tr {
      background-color: #FB28; 
}
```

and use COL's.